# Toast message: Failed to init Google DNS, switch to host IP method

Tags: samsung, security, 7.0-nougat, networking, toast-notifications

Recently, after unlocking my phone screen (Samsung J7 Pro - J730, stock ROM, Android 7 Nougat), I usually receive a toast notification saying: **"Failed to init Google DNS, switch to host IP method"**. I can guess that the toast is made after a network change (from WiFi to 3G and vice versa) because that's how it usually happens, like when I go home and the phone catches the WiFi signal. Maybe the "Google DNS" refers to the 8.8.8.8 public DNS server owned by Google.

Problem is: (1) I don't modify the network configuration at all. My IP is set to DHCP, not static and not manually configurated. And (2) it even happens on 3G network, which I cannot configure the DNS in anyway.

I have looked for the toast message everywhere and I could not find any reference at all.

My questions are:

- What is the source of this toast? Have any of you encountered this as well?
- Is this a security concern (location tracking, hacking attempts, surveillance, etc.)? Should I be worried about this at all?

Thank you!

Comment: For identifying source of this Notification try this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to beeshyams' suggestion, I downloaded the app [Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) and found out that the toast comes from a forum's app. It looks like there are no security concerns for now.